# Couldn't use bundle in Adapter - Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm on a project that, i'm getting datas from Json output. And showing them in my app. Json output includes categories in categories. I'm showing categories with listView, therefore i'm using adapters. It's all ok with FirstPageAdapter but when I switch the other, I can't get datas from FirstPageAdapter with using intent. That question([How to call getIntent() in adapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142773/how-to-call-getintent-in-adapter-class)) didn't helped me well btw.

FirstPageAdapter.java:

```
public class FirstPageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<ResponseDTO> responseDTOList;
    Context context;
    Activity activity;

    public FirstPageAdapter(List<ResponseDTO> responseDTOList, Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.responseDTOList = responseDTOList;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return responseDTOList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return responseDTOList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_main_act, viewGroup, false);
        TextView id, idCategory, parent_id, categoryName, filters, brands;
        Button categoriesButton, specsButton;

        id = view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        idCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.idCategory);
        parent_id = view.findViewById(R.id.parent_id);
        categoryName = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        filters = view.findViewById(R.id.filters);
        brands = view.findViewById(R.id.brands);
        categoriesButton = view.findViewById(R.id.childCategories);
        specsButton = view.findViewById(R.id.specs);

        id.setText("ID : "+responseDTOList.get(i).getId());
        idCategory.setText("Category ID: "+responseDTOList.get(i).getIdcategory());
        parent_id.setText("Parent ID: "+responseDTOList.get(i).getParentId());
        categoryName.setText("Category name : "+responseDTOList.get(i).getCategoryName());
        filters.setText("Filters : "+responseDTOList.get(i).getFilters());
        brands.setText("Brands : "+responseDTOList.get(i).getBrands());

        final String post = "" + responseDTOList.get(i).getId();
        final String id_category = "" + responseDTOList.get(i).getIdcategory();

        categoriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ChildCategoriesAdapter.class);
                intent.putExtra("post_id",post);
                intent.putExtra("id_category",id_category);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        specsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ChildCategoriesAdapter.class);
                intent.putExtra("post_id",post);
                intent.putExtra("id_category",id_category);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

ChildCategoriesAdapter.java:

```
public class ChildCategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<ResponseDTO> responseDTOList;
    Context context;
    Activity activity;

    public ChildCategoriesAdapter(List<ResponseDTO> responseDTOList, Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.responseDTOList = responseDTOList;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return responseDTOList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return responseDTOList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        defVars(view, viewGroup);

        return null;
    }


    public void defVars(View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_activity_child, viewGroup, false);
        Button variationsButton;
        TextView id, idCategory, parent_id, categoryName, filters, brands;

        id = view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        idCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.idCategory);
        parent_id = view.findViewById(R.id.parent_id);
        categoryName = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        filters = view.findViewById(R.id.filters);
        brands = view.findViewById(R.id.brands);
        variationsButton = view.findViewById(R.id.variationsButton);
    }

    public void request()
    {
        responseDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Call<List<ResponseDTO>> call = ManagerAll
    }


}
```

I have their Activities apart from these.

MainActivity.java(FirstPageAdapter):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirstPageAdapter adp;
    List<ResponseDTO> list;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        defVars();
        request();
    }

    public void defVars()
    {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    public void request()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        Call<List<ResponseDTO>> call = ManagerAll.getInstance().bringCall();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ResponseDTO>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ResponseDTO>> call, Response<List<ResponseDTO>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    list = response.body();
                    adp = new FirstPageAdapter(list, getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
                    listView.setAdapter(adp);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ResponseDTO>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Nothing important in ChildCategories.java

Comment: What's in BaseAdapter?

Comment: It's kinda previously made package, i didn't create it